# Microsoft Access and SQL - Update table.1 value when the record does not exist on table.2

Tags: sql, ms-access, exists

I'm having some issues with getting the code below to work. When there is not a matching invoice on the Upload.Invoice table, I would like to update the Status field of the Unprocessed/Unapproved table to 2 when it is at 7 and the invoice field is not null.

I have tried the below SQL and it is not updating the values that fit the criteria. For my test there should be 4 updates and 0 are being completed. I usually use design view and am not sure where I went wrong in the code.

```
UPDATE 
    [Unprocessed/Unapproved TC], 
    Upload 
SET 
    [Unprocessed/Unapproved TC].Status = 2, 
    [Unprocessed/Unapproved TC].[Resolution Date] = Date()
WHERE 
    (([Unprocessed/Unapproved TC].Status)=7) 
    AND 
    (([Unprocessed/Unapproved TC].Invoice) Is Not Null) 
    AND 
    (Not Exists 
        (
            SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                [Unprocessed/Unapproved TC]
            WHERE 
                [Unprocessed/Unapproved TC].Invoice = [Upload].Invoice
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up the formatting Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should query the upload table in the not exists clause and also just refer to the table you want to update in the update clause, so try this instead (but be sure to make a backup before you run it):

```
UPDATE 
    [Unprocessed/Unapproved TC]     
SET 
    [Unprocessed/Unapproved TC].Status = 2, 
    [Unprocessed/Unapproved TC].[Resolution Date] = Date()
WHERE 
    (([Unprocessed/Unapproved TC].Status)=7) 
    AND 
    (([Unprocessed/Unapproved TC].Invoice) Is Not Null) 
    AND 
    (Not Exists 
        (
            SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                [Upload]
            WHERE 
                [Unprocessed/Unapproved TC].Invoice = [Upload].Invoice
        )
    );
```